# Edit specific object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an edit view. In this view I got a dropdown and a render partial to a form. Like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user installations">
      <% @installations.each do |i| %>
         <li><a href="#">Installation<%= i.installation_id%></a></li>
       <% end %>
</ul>

<div class="ibox-content form-installations">                          
      <%= render :partial => 'installations/test'%>
      <%= render 'form_data' %>
</div>
```

The view to edit the form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @installation, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
         ...
    <%end%>
```

Controller:

```
   def edit
        @installations = current_user.installations
        @installation = current_user.installations[0]
    end
```

So in this point I can see in dropdown all installations but only can edit the first "current_user.installations[0]". So my objective is to select the installation in dropdown-menu and edit the selected installation. How I can do this?

Comment: In your `form` instead of `simple_form for @installation`  -> try `simple_form for @installations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this will be to pass the relevant `installation` to the dropdown:

```
#app/controllers/installations_controller.rb
class InstallationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @installations = current_user.installations
   end
end

#app/views/installations/index.html.erb
<%= render @installations %>

#app/views/installations/_installation.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for installation do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

I think there are some major issues with the structure of your code - which is why you're seeing these problems.

---

**1. Edit**

By definition *edit* is a `member` route...

[image]

This means that Rails expects a single resource to be loaded through that route (hence why you get `url.com/:id/edit` as the path).

The reason for this is quite simple -- Rails/Ruby are [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means that each time you `create/read/update/destroy (CRUD)`, you're doing it to an *object*.

Objects are invoked by using `@installation = Installation.new` etc... meaning if you want to edit "all" of your *installations*, you'll basically need to use one of the *collection* routes for your `Installations` resource, sending any fields to the `update` path:

```
#app/views/installations/_installation.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for installation, method: :patch do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

This *should* send the updates to the `installations#update` path of your app, making it work properly.

--

**2. Partials**

Partials are just views which can have multiple uses; you should *only* use "local" variables in them.

There are two ways to invoke local scope variables into partials:

- passing them in the `locals: {}` hash
- passing them as in the `as: :__` switch

In both instances, you're setting the "local" variables inside the partial to have data that was only available outside of it.

For example, you're calling:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @installation
```

... *inside* a partial. This is bad because you're relying on `@installation` -- you're better using `installation` and populating it as you invoke the partial (as I have done in the code above).